# ScrollView doesn't work

Tags: android, scrollview

It should be easy I know!!! I watched tutorial, searched for approx. 2 hours and tried like 15 different methods (maybe more) and still can't get it to work.

**In my app when I focus/select EditText and keyboard pops out I can't scroll down to input other text**

**AndroidManifest.xml** > **activity** set to **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"**

here is the **layout>main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtProduct1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Produkt 1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInfo1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="cena / hmot: 0 eur"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
            android:width="140dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPrice1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Cena"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtWeight1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Hmotnosť"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/question" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPrice2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Cena"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtWeight2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Hmotnosť"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInfo2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="cena / hmot: 0 eur"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
            android:width="140dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtProduct2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Produkt 2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="#264865"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="160dp" />
 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Your not actually asking a question .. but the `TextView` with id `txtInfo1` & `txtInfo2` have `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` , I'd change that to `wrap_content` for a start

Comment: I assume you have that closing </ScrollView> tag, right? Also, please describe exactly what is not working? Error at compile time? Or does it not appear as you wished it would?

Comment: @AmokraneChentir Yeah he just had the formatting wrong

Comment: isnt eclipse showing any errror?Actually it is working fyn in my emulator with </scrollview>

Comment: "still can't get it to work" is a pointless statement. If you wish assistance, you need to provide **complete** and **precise** symptoms.

Comment: ScrollView is closed.. and no errors in eclipse.

Comment: what is this  15 different methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Make sure the ScrollView only has one child,
2. As already mentioned, make sure you have a closing tag
3. The following code worked for me...

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>
> <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
>   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>   android:fillViewport="true" >
>
>   <LinearLayout
>           android:orientation="vertical"
>           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
>
>           <!--I added more views here! -->
>
>   </LinearLayout>
> </ScrollView>
> ```

Hope this helps.

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Update from comments... Screenshot of when I copy and pasted your code (on a Samsung Galaxy S).  Working!

[image: Your layout on a Galaxy S]

---

Comment: 1. It has only one child, like your sample; 2. Closing tag is there;

Comment: To clarify, does the scrolling never work, or just when the virtual keyboard is present?

Comment: I've checked it when the keyboard is visible too, but I can't scroll to the bottom to see other inputs. I'm thinking to change height of LinearLayout (current height + keyboard height), when EditText is focused.

Comment: You can scroll but the keyboard is in the way of the second half of the screen? Screenshots would probably help clarify your question

Comment: I copied and pasted your layout code into a new project (just replacing your drawables with ic_launcher).  When I ran it on my Samsung Galaxy S the views DID scroll up to reveal the EditTexts sitting under the keyboard, so I'm afraid I don't know why it wouldn't work for you...

Comment: thanx... I've removed all added stuff from manifest and found out that the problem is **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"**, any ideas why is that?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.   I experimented and found removing Fullscreen produced your desired scrolling effect.  (That is having @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar worked  as desired). I would have looked at themes.xml source code as suggested in this article [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles) but unfortunately looking at the source  code seems more complicated than it used to be...

Comment: I've searched and tried a few different ways, but with no luck. In the end I used **@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar**, if I ever find an answer I'll post it here :) , thanx again Mel.

Comment: @vstruhar have you found why it occurs? Is it possible it's a bug that occurs when you hide the status bar?

Comment: No, I haven't.. I just stoped using Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't witten `</ScrollView>` at last, Just Add and Ya it is done.

Comment: Please give such answer in comments

Comment: @ShahzadImam : Okie ya i got you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had an OnTouchListener on the ScrollView that returned true in the onTouch method. This broke scrolling. Changing it to return false fixed the problem.