# How would I use a ScrollView inside a FrameLayout?

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, master-detail, android-framelayout

I'm having a lot of trouble getting my ScrollView to function properly. I'm using a Master-Detail design.  The Master scrolls, since it's a listView.  The Detail when selected will display the scrollbar implemented in my XML for a couple seconds when the Activity is inflated before disappearing (Stackoverflow won't allow me to post the screenshot of the error since this is my first post)

When I try to scroll the Detail Activity with touch input nothing happens.   I've tried copying and pasting Mel's solution to what seems like an identical problem in the post at [ScrollView doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956106/scrollview-doesnt-work).  I've also tried every conceivable combination of match_parent and fill_parent for the parent, child, and ScrollView itself.  Any help is appreciated. My XML code is below:

```css
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ItemDetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:stretchColumns="1, 2"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bmp1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:stretchColumns="1, 2">

                     <!-- Table Row 0 -->
                     <TableRow
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:id="@+id/tableRow0">
                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/priWeapon"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:text="@string/priWeapon" android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
                             android:gravity="left"
                             android:padding="5dp"/>
                         <EditText
                             android:id="@+id/priWeaponEditText"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:text="@string/NA" android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="bold"
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:focusable="false"
                             android:layout_weight="1"
                             android:cursorVisible="false"
                             android:longClickable="false"/>
                     </TableRow>

                     <!-- Table Row 1 -->
                     <TableRow
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/priWeaponRange"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:text="@string/priMaxRange" android:textColor="#000"
                             android:gravity="left"
                             android:padding="5dp"/>
                         <EditText
                             android:id="@+id/priWeaponRangeEditText"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:text="@string/NA" android:textSize="14sp"
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:focusable="false"
                             android:layout_weight="1"
                             android:cursorVisible="false"
                             android:longClickable="false"/>
                     </TableRow>

                </TableLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution!  Instead of trying to apply the formatting to the Activity XML itself, I cut and pasted it into one of the Activity's Fragment XMLs, which didn't have a frameLayout. Because of this change it now scrolls perfectly while maintaining the title bar on top throughout the scroll, exactly the behavior that I wanted.  I've posted the final code below.  If you have a solution that would still allow me to use a scrollView inside a FrameLayout though I'd be more than happy to see it for future reference. Thank you for your help!

```css
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true"
    >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1, 2"
    >

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/item_detail"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        tools:context=".ItemDetailFragment"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bmp1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <TableLayout

        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:stretchColumns="1, 2">

        <!-- Table Row 0 -->
        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow0">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/priWeapon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/priWeapon" android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="5dp"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/priWeaponEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/NA" android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:longClickable="false"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is to use the maximal screen size for the `ImageView` and then scroll down to the (at first invisible) `TableLayout`? Thats afaik not possible. When you set `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` on ImageView it uses the the maximum possible (in your example all of the screen size) space. So no `TableLayout` is rendered and there is no need for scrolling. You should set the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the ImageView.

Some notes on the source code:

- Use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`. It's renamed since API Level 8
- You have a useless `android:layout_below="@id/picture"` in the `TableLayout`. May an artifact from a previous version with `RelativeLayout`?
- Remove the namespace definitions in the `TableLayout`